# Jquery find the text field by the text within it

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to find a text field by the text entered inside.

My exact situation is that,

I have about 4-5 text fields, and i need to find those text fields which doesn't have any text entered, i.e whose value = "" .

Any help would be of great use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
var $input = $('input[type=text]').filter(function(){
   return this.value === ''
})
```

Comment: It might be worth using trim() here, so fields with spaces in them count as empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method given by @undefined. The following selection has worked for me, you can try that:

```
    $(":text[value=]").get()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:text').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; });
```

or

```
$('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
```

or

```
$('input:text[value=""]');
```